# Unable to load data from a csv file properly in my sql database

Tags: sql

I am unable to load data fully into my sql database, though I am successfully able to upload it via simply importing the csv via workbench.

I have successfully imported the file via workbench but somehow its not working with LOAD INFILE.

create table address_details(CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL , CUST_CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
CUST_STREET VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, Zipcode VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID, Zipcode)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:/TEMP/address_details.csv' INTO TABLE address_details FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 ROWS (CUSTOMER_ID, CUST_CITY, CUST_STREET, ZIPCODE);

mysql> select * from address_details;
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | CUST_CITY | CUST_STREET                    | Zipcode   |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------+
    |001      | New York  | Bedford Hills                  | 10507
    |002      | New York  | Cold Spring                    | 10516
  |00003      | Torento   | DONORA DR                      | M4B 1B3
     |04      | Brisban   |  Nundah                        | 4012
   |0005      | Mumbai    | Mumbai                         | 230532
  |00006      | Torento   | AVIS CRES                      | M4B 1B7

[Idealoutput via workbench uploaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smQPf.jpg)

Comment: What version/type of SQL are you using? MySQL? Oracle? Transact-SQL?

Comment: How do you mean it's "not working"?  What happens when you try?  Do you get an error message?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: Version: 8.0.11 @AndyLester The ideal output image shows that it should be clean like C00001,C00002 but when i am loading file iwth "Load Infile then for column 1 it is slicing the initial part of column 1. C00001 is being shown as |001, C00002 as |002

Comment: @MarkMoretto Got the solution! I added '\n' with '\t' and that worked